# Based on Multiple checkbox selection, “mailto:” link changes to “mailto: multiple variables” using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a form. The way it would work is that the user chooses up to 3 options from  10 multiple selection checkboxes. They then click the confirm location button. Finally they click the send email link. Basically when they click the confirm location button, it changes the mailto link in the send email link, based on their selection (up to 3) in the multiple checkboxes. However, what I cannot figure is how to set up the multiple selection checkboxes(with a max limit of 3 and min of 1), and then add the single/multiple email values in the mailto link.
I have managed to do this for a drop-down list (only 1 selection, hence only 1 email), but I cannot figure out the above. Please help!

```
<form>Select your place:
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="email@domain.com">Location 1</option>
        <option value="email2@domain.com">Location 2</option>
        <option value="email3@domain.com">Location 3</option>
        <option value="email4@domain.com">Location 4</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Confirm Location</button>
<a id="myEmailList" href="mailto:">Send email</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayResult() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    t = x.value
    document.getElementById("myEmailList").href = "mailto:"t;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JS**

```
  function displayResult() {
    var se = document.getElementById("myEmailList"),
        send = document.getElementById("send"),
        x = document.getElementById("mySelect"),
        l = [],

        // get all checkboxes inside our fieldset that are checked

        list = x.querySelectorAll(":checked");

    // loop the list and push the email stored in value to our array list 
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        l.push(list[i].value);
    }

    // use array.join(",") to create a nice email list deliminated by commas
    send.href = "mailto:" + l.join(", ");
    se.innerHTML = l.join(", ");
  }
```

**HTML**

```
    <input type="checkbox" value="email1@domain.com">l1
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="email2@domain.com">l2
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="email3@domain.com">l3
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" value="email4@domain.com">l4
        <br>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Confirm Location</button>
<a id="send" href="mailto:">Send email</a>

<div id="myEmailList"></div>
```

**FIDDLE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oojmygwy/1/

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful. However I still have a single list to select from. I'm trying to figure out how to use checkboxes instead.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I first off make it with a radio box group as it made a lot more sense, then i thought I should stick to your design. Ill change it for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use checkboxes and also the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oojmygwy/1/

Comment: No worries, Thanks!! It works perfectly in jsfiddle, but when I use it in WordPress page it doesn't. Can you please help me out? (My original code works fine in WordPress).

Comment: Never mind, I used a plugin to add the JavaScript onto my WordPress page. Thanks so much again, that code worked perfectly!! :D